# hpple HTML Parsing Library Not Parsing Correctly on iOS 7

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, parsing

I am using the hpple parsing library in my iOS app. https://github.com/topfunky/hpple

I am having a problem where the parser is not correctly parsing my HTML page on iOS 7. It is correctly parsed on iOS 6 and I get the returned objects. On iOS 7 I am returned only a partial parse and a wrong one. The library incorrectly reads the HTML on iOS 7. I have tried debugging the problem and have concluded that the problem lies in this method.

```
NSArray *PerformXPathQuery(xmlDocPtr doc, NSString *query)
{
  xmlXPathContextPtr xpathCtx;
  xmlXPathObjectPtr xpathObj;

  /* Create xpath evaluation context */
  xpathCtx = xmlXPathNewContext(doc);
  if(xpathCtx == NULL)
    {
      //NSLog(@"Unable to create XPath context.");
      return nil;
    }

  /* Evaluate xpath expression */
  xpathObj = xmlXPathEvalExpression((xmlChar *)[query cStringUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding], xpathCtx);
  if(xpathObj == NULL) {
    //NSLog(@"Unable to evaluate XPath.");
    xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);
    return nil;
  }

  xmlNodeSetPtr nodes = xpathObj->nodesetval;
  if (!nodes)
    {
      //NSLog(@"Nodes was nil.");
      xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj);
      xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);
      return nil;
    }

  NSMutableArray *resultNodes = [NSMutableArray array];
  for (NSInteger i = 0; i < nodes->nodeNr; i++)
    {
      NSDictionary *nodeDictionary = DictionaryForNode(nodes->nodeTab[i], nil,false);
      if (nodeDictionary)
        {
          [resultNodes addObject:nodeDictionary];
        }
    }

  /* Cleanup */
  xmlXPathFreeObject(xpathObj);
  xmlXPathFreeContext(xpathCtx);

  return resultNodes;
}
```

doc and query are not nil when this method is called. I don't know how to log the other classes in this method and I do not know which one of them returns the wrong parse. Maybe the problem lies in Apple's libxml2.dylib

I do not know exactly what the code does in the method until the end of the method. Any help will be greatly appreciated as I am stumped why the library cannot parse on iOS 7 the same HTML page it can parse on iOS 6.

On iOS 7 this library correctly parses other HTML pages in other apps. The code I use to parse initiate the parser is

```
 NSData *htmlData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:dataURL];

    TFHpple *dataParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:htmlData];

    NSString *dataXpathQueryString = @"//td[3]";
    NSArray *dataNodes = [dataParser searchWithXPathQuery:dataXpathQueryString];

    NSMutableArray *newData = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:0];
    for (TFHppleElement *element in dataNodes) {

        data = [[GFCData alloc] init];
        [newData addObject:data];
        data.title = [[element firstChild] content];

        data.title = [data.title stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet whitespaceAndNewlineCharacterSet]];
    }
```

where dataURL is http://www.gfchurch.com/ru/pages/video.php?a=5&b=51&c=37

I can provide more information if needed.

Comment: What is your input data to parse?

Comment: The dataURL. The HTML page link is at the bottom of the question.

Comment: The HTML in question is not valid.

Comment: Why would the HTML be valid on iOS 6 but not iOS 7?

Comment: @Mr.Russian The validness of the HTML is independent of which OS you are parsing it on. It's invalid regardless of that. Maybe the library (either the Objective-C one or libxml2) is more permissive (for whatever reason) on iOS 6 than it is on iOS 7.

Comment: Oh so it must be the permissiveness of the library. That explains it a little. Thanks

Comment: The link is no longer valid. Was the HTML the issue? Did you solve your problem? Your problem here is similar to others, more info would be useful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem was solved by not using `//` in the `searchPathQuery`. I should test this problem again because the library was updated a month ago and maybe the issue was solved.

Answer (score -2):

I solved this issue by correctly managing namespaces via @xmlXPathRegisterNs@

I was not having the issue parsing HTML, but SOAP response.

Comment: Can you please show an example of how you solved it? I solved it by not using // in the searchPathQuery.